# Add remove class on multiple input depending on characters

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have 10 input fields that I want to check have at least 2 charaters in ...

```
<input type="text" />
<input type="text" />
<input type="text" />

$('input[type="text"]').on('keyup', function(){ 
     if($(this).length > 2){
         alert('yeah')
     } else {
         alert('no');
     }
});
```

I'm using the above but I keep getting the alert "No"

Why is this?

Answer (score 1):

`$(this)` refers to jQuery object, not element's value. You need to get the value first via `$.val()` method.

Do it like this:

```
if ($(this).val().length > 2) { ... }
```

http://api.jquery.com/val/

Or as @Taplar suggested, you can simply access the `this.value` property (`this` will refer to the first matched element). This way you can speed up the code a little bit because you will not create new jQuery object instance.

```
if (this.value.length > 2) { ... }
```

Comment: Great thanks! If I want to remove a class using the else however how do I target the $(this)?

Comment: `$(this).removeClass('class-name')`

Comment: True, added a note about that.

Answer (score 1):

I'd just use `this.value` instead of making an unnecessary jQuery object.  Also using the `input` event will make the logic fire only if the value changes, and not for other keys like arrow keys and others that don't actually change the value.

```js
$('input[type="text"]').on('input', function(){ 
  console.log(this.value.trim().length > 2 ? 'yeah' : 'no');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" />
<input type="text" />
<input type="text" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('input[type="text"]').on('keyup', function(){ 
     if($(this).val().length > 2){
         console.log('yeah')
     } else {
         console.log('no');
     }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" />
<input type="text" />
<input type="text" />
```